# css not altering svg fill-opacity

Tags: css, svg

i have an arrow in an svg logo which i am trying to make semi transparent _ unfortunately the tranpsarency i created in Adobe Illustrator hasn't carried over _
there are several question&answers about svg fill-opacity on StackOverflow & some solutions which i've attempted but so far without success _
i think i'm identifying the arrow element correctly but unsure as it appears to have two ids
the complete code is available for viewing on codepen.io here >>>
http://codepen.io/maikf/pen/NbLJPJ

my code is as follows

```
html
<g id="arrow_xA0_Image_1_">
<image overflow="visible" width="491" height="144" id="arrow_xA0_Image" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64, (code sequence)

css
#arrow_xA0_Image {
  fill-opacity: 0.7;
}
```

thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: fill-opacity does not apply to image elements. opacity does though.

Comment: thanks for reply Robert _ i wrote my own answer and posted then your comment appeared : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my error was using 'fill-opacity' instead of 'opacity' 
the correct code should read

```
#arrow_xA0_Image {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```